# Fourier transform of $\frac{g_i}{e^{\frac{\epsilon_i-\mu}{kT}}-1}$? Not Gaussian like with Fermi-Dirac statistics?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, fourier-analysis

This equation $\bar n_i=\frac{g_i}{e^{\frac{\epsilon_i-\mu}{kT}}-1}$ is Fermi-Dirac statistics where variables are defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics). The classical equation i.e. the Maxwell Boltzman equation is Gaussian function where its Fourier transform with respect to location is also Gaussian. I need to somehow express the Fermi-Dirac statistics in terms of $\bar x$ in order to calculate the Fourier transform with respect to $\bar x$, somehow perhaps with energies or with $g_i$ -- not clear yet how.

> **What is the Fourier transform with respect to location such as coordinate $\bar x$ with Fermi-Dirac statistics?**

**Background**

> According to my tutor: when you do the Fourier-transform
>   $$\phi(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
>  f(x)e^{-ikt}dx$$ with Maxwell Boltzman, you get the frequency
>   distribution. The inverse Fourier transform is just
>   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
>  \phi(k)e^{-ikx}dk.$$
>
> I expected that I would get it here also but it is not Gaussian -- a
>   problem?
>
> According to Wolfram, Fourier Transform of the exponential function
>   $e^{-k_0\left| \bar x \right|}$ is a damped exponential cosine
>   integral more
>   [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformExponentialFunction.html)
>   -- a Lorentzian function. They look similar to Gaussian function, more [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html), but not
>   satisfying the Gaussian.
>
> [image]
>
> I don't know whether the interperation as frequency distribution is
>   still valid even though we get a different function as with the
>   Fourier Transform of the Gaussian.
>
> Gaussian-Gaussian change is bijective but I cannot immediately see it with Fermi-Dirac-Lorentzian change. How can I be sure to get a nice bell-shaped distribution when I do a Fourier transform on arbitrary function? I know Fourier transform of a single sine wave is just a peak but I don't know how it really works with arbitrary functions such as Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein statistics.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber good point, I need to express the energies or the degenerazy $g_i$ somehow in terms of $\bar x$ -- I don't know yet how to do it, have to think over it...

Comment: ...I may be integrating with respect to wrong coordinate, chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7363751#7363751). The goal is to get frequency distribution.

Comment: It's been a long time. I don't think you need it anymore. But hey, for other people like me that got here. I don't know if this could help http://lambda.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/~sirotori/URAitems/Report/Nuclear%20Physics%20Lecture%20report02(Maeda)%20reference.pdf